# I'm trying out Node.js on EC2. Should I do it on a 32 bit server or a 64 bit ubuntu server?

Tags: javascript, linux, unix, node.js, amazon-ec2

Which is better for Node.js?  btw, these will be tiny servers, because of cheap .

Comment: I'm running it on a 64 bit Ubuntu micro image and it runs great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's hardly any reason to consider 32-bit systems on the server side. It's only for working with legacy programs, but that's not what we're talking about here so go on and pick 64 bit.

Comment: Do you really believe that a "tiny server" can afford to have the increased pointer size that comes with going 64-bit?

Comment: Ignacio, why wouldn't they? Isn't the micro instance on EC2 over 600 MB of RAM?

Comment: @Ignatio, the massive improvements in response times with 64-bit kernels far outweigh the loss in memory. You're speaking as if the pointer size was prohibitive.

Comment: @iconiK, could you link to some evidence that 64-bit kernels exhibit "massive improvements in response times", I don't understand how increasing the address range and register sizes improves anything speed-wise, except for particular Maths operations, such as encryption.

Comment: @David: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/11/64-bit-desktop-vs-64-bit-server.html ; it's not just register size, it's also register count.